# When my toggle is selected as yes I want a default value to be inputted into my dropdown box below, how do I do that?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Here is an image of it. I want the default value to be Open when the toggle is selected as yes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the Default setting for the dropdown control to a formula along these lines:

```
If(MyToggle.Value=true,"Three","One")
```

[image]

If the control is a Combobox, which is what's used for a SharePoint Choice column, then the items are records, not just a list of text.  For a combo box you need to change the property for "**DefaultSelectedItems**" and set it to something like this:

```
If(MyToggle.Value,{Value:"Three"},Parent.Default)
```

Make sure that the value you are using is a valid one according to the SharePoint choice column definition.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Is it a dropdown or a combo box? Because the above works just fine with a dropdown.

Comment: It's a choice list from a sharepoint list.

Comment: Yeah, you said dropdown. A Sharepoint Choice field does not use a dropdown control. That's a combo box. Give me a moment and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I added the details for a combo box to my answer.

Comment: See [Choice columns here](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/default-values-for-complex-sharepoint-types/)